# Change mirror modifier to recognize other vertex groups like ri/le 2.79

Tags: vertices, mirror

Can I change mirror modifier to recognize other vertex groups (weight painting) like ri/le? I have a specific armature, and changing all the names to R/L and then back to ri/le is tedious.